# How to implement SAML 2.0 in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and the requirement is to implement SAML 2.0 authentication for the application. So to do that what's needs to added in code side. I also went through different articles but nothing is clear for what's need to be added in the application side for adding SAML configuration. so please suggest the steps or some sample code to use in the application.

I'm looking for some sample code with SAML 2.0 configuration